# Angular ngIf condition breaking javascript logic

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following nested dropdown list. The child items are initially hidden and clicking on the parent toggles an "open" class to display the children.
I am trying to conditionally display the entire list with an `ngIf`, which works correctly. However, when my condition is true the open class toggle no longer works. Any reason why simply adding the `ngIf` condition breaks this functionality?

```
         <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="isMHQEnabled"> //toggles correctly without the if condition
                <a class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="fal fa-exchange"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exchange"></i>
                    <span class="title">Broker Transfers</span>
                    <span class="arrow">
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-down">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="initiateBrokerTransfer()">
                            <i class="fal fa-message-dots"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-message-dots"></i>
                            <span class="title">Transfer Request</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="navigate('brokertransfer')"> 
                            <i class="fal fa-list-check"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-list-check"></i>
                            <span class="title">Transfer Status</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: try using `[hidden]="!isMHQEnabled"` Sometimes *ngIf prevents event handlers from being attached

Comment: Which element is the open class being applied to?